# CFDirectory is saying that it can't copy files to destination directory

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfdirectory

We have a simple script that copies files across from a base install folder we created to house files for our application. When we choose to install a new site, based on these files, it's saying that the destination directory can't be found.

```
<cfset variables.destination = "#variables.base_path#\#variables.destination#\wwwroot\">
<!--- actually copying the base installation to the new location--->
<cfdirectory  action="copy" directory="#mycontent.directory#\#mycontent.name#" destination="#variables.destination#" recurse="yes" >
<!--- end copying the system files --->
```

The `wwwroot` directory will always exist on the system. We are trying to push files into that folder. However it's throwing an error and won't allow it to go through.

The actual error message being caught is:

> The specified directory C:\home\domainname.com\wwwroot\ could not be
>   created. The most likely cause of this error is that
>   C:\home\domainname.com\wwwroot\ already exists on your file system.

Comment: _"its saying that the destination directory cant be found"_ - Don't describe the error, post the exact message!
If you're certain the path is correct and the directory exists (do a cfdump of variables.destination to make certain it's what you think it is) then it's probably a permission issue.

Comment: What is the error? Assuming you have double-checked the variables are getting set as expected. Also, `destination is Path of the destination directory. If not an absolute path, it is relative to the source directory.`

Comment: just added in the error message we are catching when it occurs. it doesnt always happen but when it does it makes us wonder what is going on..

Comment: Looks like a pretty informative message.  How do you interpret it?

Comment: I'm trying to fill out the wwwroot directory not create an actual directory... is there an option here to do this ?

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is to use cfdirectory to list all the files therein.  Then loop through the contents and use cffile to copy the files.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following in ColdFusion 11:

```
<cfdirectory directory="//users/myname/sites/test/source"
    destination="//users/myname/sites/test/dest"
    action="copy" recurse="yes">
```

This works fine, whether the folder has been previously created or not.  Also, it seems that the recurse attribute is supported, despite the documentation only stating that it is valid for list and delete actions.

https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfdirectory

As it seems to happen some times but not others perhaps it is a timing issue or with large files / multiple folders?